# format time difference with %H

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I format a time-difference value, computed using `time-subtract`? Consider this simple example:

```
(let*
    ((before (current-time))
     (after (progn (sit-for 0.25) (current-time)))
     (diff (time-subtract after before)))
  (insert (format "before: %s--%s\n" before (format-time-string "%Hh%Mm%S.%3Ns" before)))
  (insert (format "after:  %s--%s\n" after (format-time-string "%Hh%Mm%S.%3Ns" after)))
  (insert (format "diff:   %s--%s--%s\n" diff (format-time-string "%s.%3Ns" diff)
                  (format-time-string "%Hh%Mm%S.%3Ns" diff))))
```

Evaluating it inserts the following:

```
before: (22616 21856 296901 800000)--13h47m12.296s
after:  (22616 21856 552345 800000)--13h47m12.552s
diff:   (0 0 255444 0)--0.255s--16h00m00.255s
```

The difference between the two timestamps is about 250ms. But formatting it using `format-time-string` with format string `"%Hh%Mm%S.%3Ns"` produces 16.

**Shouldn't it be 0?**

Comment: you might want to close your question by [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"16"` comes from your timezone.

I think if you do `(format-time-string "%Hh%Mm%S.%3Ns" diff 0)`, you will see the result you expected (i.e., `0`).

Comment: Thanks. If I spent half the time reading help that I spend in formatting the question...

Comment: ... then I wouldn't earn the points for answering it :-)  (you are welcome)